# Prove that $\tanh (\cosh^{-1} (x)) = \frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, inverse-function, hyperbolic-functions, function-and-relation-composition

**Prove that**

$
\tanh (\cosh^{-1} (x)) = \dfrac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x}
$
,

**by using that**

$
\tanh (x) = \dfrac{e^x-e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}
$
,

**and that**

$
\cosh^{-1} (x) = \ln (x+\sqrt{x^2-1})
$
.

*After substituting $\cosh^{-1}$ into $x$ in $\tanh (x)$, I'm not sure what to do:*

$
\tanh (\cosh^{-1} (x)) = \dfrac{e^{\ln (x+\sqrt{x^2-1})}-e^{-\ln (x+\sqrt{x^2-1})}}{e^{\ln (x+\sqrt{x^2-1})}+e^{-\ln (x+\sqrt{x^2-1})}} = \dfrac{(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})-\dfrac{1}{x+\sqrt{x^2-1}}}{(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})+\dfrac{1}{x+\sqrt{x^2-1}}}
$

*I've tried multiplying both numerator and denominator with $x+\sqrt{x^2-1}$ and using a binomial theorem of 2nd degree, but I have no idea if that was in the right direction.*

Comment: The equality is true according to Wikipedia (Inverse hyperbolic functions > "Composition of hyperbolic and inverse hyperbolic functions").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's some tricks to make the algebra tidier, and you really need them for this kind of problem.

Define $s = \sqrt{x^2-1}$ and $c = (x + \sqrt{x^2-1}) = (x + s)$.

Note $s^2 = x^2 - 1$. From here on we use $s$ similar to the way you'd usually use $i$.

Then:
\begin{align}
\tanh(\cosh^{-1}(x)) &= \tanh(\ln(c)) = \frac{c-\frac 1c}{c + \frac 1c} = \frac{c^2 - 1}{c^2 +1} = \frac{(x+s)^2 -1} {(x+s)^2 +1}\\
&= \frac{x^2 + s^2 -1 + 2xs}{x^2 + s^2 +1 + 2xs}\\
&= \frac{2x^2 - 2 + 2xs}{2 x^2 + 2xs}\\
&= \frac{x(x+s) - 1}{x(x+s)}\\
&= \frac{x(x+s) - 1}{x(x+s)} \cdot \frac{x-s}{x-s}\\
&= \frac{x(x^2-s^2) - (x-s)}{x(x^2-s^2)}\\
&= \frac{x(1) - (x-s)}{x(1)}\\
&= \frac{s}{x}\\
&= \frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x}
\end{align}

Comment: Did you mean $s^2 = x^2 - 1$?

Comment: @EdwardChen You treat $s$ as a variable whose square is $x^2-1$.

Answer (score 4):

You have\begin{align}\tanh\left(\cosh^{-1}(x)\right)&=\frac{\sinh\left(\cosh^{-1}(x)\right)}{\cosh\left(\cosh^{-1}(x)\right)}\\&=\frac{\sqrt{\cosh^2\left(\cosh^{-1}(x)\right)-1}}x\\&=\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}x.\end{align}

Comment: Which identity? I have used the fact that $\tanh=\frac{\sinh}{\cosh}$, which is the definition of $\tanh$, and the fact that $\cosh^2-\sinh^2=1$.